# Regular expression to extract a number of steps

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a localized string that looks something like this in English:

> "
>   5 Mile(s)
>   5,252 Step(s)
>   "

My app is localized both in left-to-right and right-to-left languages so I don't want to make assumptions either about the ordering of the `step(s)` or about the formatting of the number (e.g. 5,252 can be 5.252 depending on user locale). So I need to account for possibilities that can include things like

> Step(s) 5.252

as well as what's above.

A few other caveats

- All I know is that if the `Step(s)` line is in there, it will be on its own line (hence in my regex I require \n at each end of the string)
- No guarantee that the `Mile(s)` information will be in the string at all, let alone whether it will be before or after `Step(s)`

Here's my attempt at pattern extraction:

```
NSString *patternString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\n(([0-9,\\.]*)\s*%@|%@\s*([0-9,\\.]*))\\n",
    NSLocalizedString(@"Step(s)",nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Step(s)",nil)];
```

There appear to be two problems with this:

- XCode is indicating `Unknown escape sequence '\s'` for the second `\s` in the pattern string above
- No matches are being found even for strings like the following:

> 0.2 Mile(s)
>   1,482 Step(s)

Ideally I would extract the `1,482` out of this string in a way that is localization friendly. How should I modify my regex?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to extract the miles as well. but to clarify, you *only* want the steps?

Comment: Right-to-left is the wrong term here. In an RTL language the data is *displayed* in a way that the number is to the right of the word, but **the order of the characters is still the same**: `\d+ \w+` would work for Hebrew. It still might be possible that a locale prefers the number after the word. One example is currency: [$20 vs. 20$](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/11341/220)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is close, although in `Obj-C` you need to double-escape the  `\s` and `(s)`:

```
^(([0-9,.]*)\\s*%@|%@\\s*([0-9,.]*))$
```

In your `NSLocalizedString` you likely also need to escape the parentheses enclosing `(s)`:

```
 NSString *patternString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^(([\\d,.]+)\\s%@|%@\\s([\\d,.]+))$",
      NSLocalizedString(@"Step\\(s\\)",nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Step\\(s\\)",nil)];
```

If you don't escape `(s)` then the regex engine is probably going to interpret it as a capture group.

*Looking at* `NSLog` *you can see what the pattern actually reads like:*

```
NSLog(@"patternString: %@", patternString);
```

**Output:**

```
patternString: ^(([\d,.]+)\sStep\(s\)|Step\(s\)\s([\d,.]+))$
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as the regex, perhaps this approach might work - it simply matches (with named groups) each couplet of numbers in sequence, with the assumption the first is miles and the second is steps. Decimals in the `.` or `,` form are optional:

```
(?<miles>\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?).*?(?<steps>\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)
```

(and i think it should be `\\s`) - i'm not an ios guy, but if you can use a regex literal it would be way more readable.

[regular expression demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8X8tJ/2)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I should elaborate my answer above to indicate that I don't want to assume the `Miles` portion is in there at all.

Comment: His solution does not mention "miles". `(?<miles>...)` is just the name of the group you can refer to for easy extraction. It does not match anything.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to ask - Why is `Mile(s)` mentioned in the question at all?

And now to my two bits - you could simply use a positive look-ahead:

```
^(?=.*Step\(s\))[^\d]*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)
```

It makes sure the expected word is present on the line, and then captures the number on it, allowing for localized, optional, decimal separator and decimals. This way it doesn't matter if the numer is before, or after, the "word".

It doesn't take localization of the "word" into account, but that you seem to have handled by yourself ;)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mN8rHN/3).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the `Mile(s)` part may not be in the string at all I'm assuming it isn't relevant to the regular expression. As I understand from the question, you just need to capture the number of steps and nothing else. On this basis, here's a modified version of your existing regex:

```
NSString *patternString = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^(?:([0-9,.]*)\\s*%@|%@\\s*([0-9,.]*))$",
    NSLocalizedString(@"Step\\(s\\)",nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Step\\(s\\)",nil)];
```

Demo:
https://www.regex101.com/r/Q6ff1b/1

This is based on the following tips/modifications:

1. Use the `m` (= `UREGEX_MULTILINE`) flag option when creating the regex to specify that `^` and `$` match the start and end of each line. This is more sophisticated than using `\n` as it will also handle the start and end of the string where this might not be present. See [here](http://www.icu-project.org/userguide/regexp).
2. Always use a double backslash (`\\`) for regex escaping - otherwise NSString will interpret the single backslash to be escaping the next character and convert it before it gets to the regex.
3. Literal parentheses need to be escaped - e.g. `Step\\(s\\)` instead of `Step(s)`.
4. Characters within a character class (i.e. anything within the `[]` square brackets) don't need to be escaped - so it would be `.` rather than `\\.` - the latter.
5. If you are using `(x|y|...)` as a choice and don't need it to be a capturing group, use `?:` after the first parenthesis to ensure it doesn't get captured - i.e. `(?:x|y|...)`.